# Sublime syntax highlighting perl qw, qq, q not working fully

Tags: perl, newline, sublimetext2, color-scheme

From 1 week i use sublime. And i'm very pleased. But i have little problem. I write in perl with sublime.

Here is the problem:

[image]

Sublime did not recognize that `'some string` is quoted and `$test_scalar` and everything after it like it is string. When i type it like that:

[image]
There is no problem.

I tried with the `Perl.tmLanguage` file, but i did not understand it.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Haven't you switched the images? A single quote is not special inside a `qq(...)`.

Comment: Yes. Because i can not put images. Some admin put them. Thank you!

Comment: So Sublime doesn't handle whitespace after `qq` correctly. Why is that a SO question rather than a bug report?

Answer (score 3):

Perl is one of the few programming languages that use this type of construct for quoting strings, and many program editors simply don't get it.

Imagine you're writing a syntax highlighter, and you have to understand all of these are the same:

```
my $string = "this is my string";
my $string = qq(This is my string);
my $string = qq/This is my string/;
my $string = qq@This is my string@;
my $string = qq
    (This is my string);
```

Your syntax highlighter would have to understand that `q`, `qq`, and `qx` are quoting options, and that the character following them (after possible white space) is the character that's doing the quoting. Oh, and also that if the character is a `(`, a `{`, or a `[`, the closing quote is a `)`, `}`, or a `]`. And, that this can be on more than one line. And, you really only need this for Perl.

I know that [VIM](http://www.vim.org) can handle the qq quoting issue, but many other program editors I have tried failed. Even Stackoverflow's syntax highlighter (Google's prettify) fails.

Try [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) or [Textpad](http://www.textpad.com) if you're on Windows. Or, try Eclipse with the EPIC editor. I believe that one also works.

Comment: I was using Notepad++, but i think that sublime is better and want to star using it.

Comment: And also `my $string = qq qThis is my stringq`!

Comment: I remember reading that even a <NL> would also work as a parameter, but I can't seem to get `qq` to use it. I love the _quote string_ feature, but only Perl does it and so most text editors just don't handle it too well. I knew it took several iterations of VIM to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Because Perl5 can't be statically parsed, editors have to make guesses about syntax. Could they do a better job in this case? Probably, but do keep in mind that it's impossible to do this perfectly.

In any case, your best bet is to get in touch with the author of the Perl syntax highlighting plugin for your editor.

Comment: I think the game is not worth the candle.

Comment: This is not the problem in this case. It's simply that Sublime doesn't handle whitespace after `qq` properly.

Answer (score 0):

As you said there is no problem and no syntax error. It is normal behavior either for sublime or vim editor. When you go on write qq operator on next line then highlighting string doesn't works on either editors.

Answer (score 0):

[cperl-mode.el](https://github.com/jrockway/cperl-mode) for Emacs does the job:

[image: Emacs screenshot]

Maybe you can take a look at it's source and try to use the same rules in Sublime or at last point this to the plugin author.